# Is there a way to hide Chrome's "User Profile" and "Extensions" areas?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to hide the area on chrome pointed out by the red arrow?

[image]

I am running Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS 10.13.6 (17G65).

When I right click the area, nothing happens, none UX interaction.

`chrome://flags` would launch this page, is it called **The profile picture**?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have circle as a single area, is actually two (or possibly three) areas:

- Extensions (None shown in your screenshot, but this could be useful for other users)
- Extensions Toolbar Menu
- Profiles

You can hide any extension icons by right-clicking on them and selecting "Hide in Chrome menu".

The 'puzzle piece' icon that you see there is the *Extensions Toolbar Menu*, you can disable is by searching for that term in `chrome://flags` and setting it to `default` or `disabled`.

However, the profile picture is not removable at this time. There used to be an option to hide it under `chrome://flags`, but that seems to have been an experimental feature and is no longer available.

That means, for logged in users it seems the best solution is to set your profile picture to a solid block that's the same colour as your Chrome Theme. For logged out users, there's only the default profile icon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please take a look at the last screen shot. is it **the profile picture** you mentioned.

Comment: There is no option in the `chrome://flags` page to turn off the profile picture in your version of Chrome. I believe that was last available around Chrome v69.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean now. Yes, that puzzle piece looking icon is the Extensions Toolbar Menu.

Comment: "set your profile picture to a solid block" Does that work while logged out as well?

Comment: @Mast No, if you were logged out you would get a generic silhouette profile icon.

Comment: @MichaelFrank So that doesn't fix the problem for people who don't sign in.

Comment: No, there is no solution for people that aren't logged in. Perhaps Firefox?

Comment: I cannot find this flag in Chrome/Edge as of writing. However, it can still be enabled through a shortcut's target field or cmd. [1](https://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-extensions-menu-button-in-google-chrome-toolbar/)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use Chrome w/o displaying your user profile icon, you can use Incognito mode from the menu control next to the profile icon. It doesn't remove that area from Chrome but it does put a default Incognito icon in place of your profile icon.

[image]

The shortcut is Ctrl + Shift + N.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how this would help OP.

Comment: If the motivation for removing that area of Chrome is partly coming from hiding profile icon, e.g. during screen-sharing, presentations, etc.